# Cannot changing JSON from a mongoDB query unless I copy it into new variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean

I've created a MEAN app that returns some JSON, I wanted to create a simple function to change a date field in the JSON before displaying it - however i can only do this if i make a **copy of the data into a new variable**. Can someone explain why this is the case? I thought a knew javascript pretty well until this!! Is this to do with scope or a mongoDB thing?

my Route:

```html
 JobsImportCtrl = require('../controllers/jobsImportCtrl'); 

module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/api/jobs', function (req, res) {
        Jobsctrl.getJobs(res);
    });
```

My controller:

```js
var Jobspretty = require('../helpers/jobspretty'); // pretty job dates etc

module.exports = {
  // get all jobs
  getJobs: function(res)  {


      Job.find(function (err, jobs){
          // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
          if (err) {
              res.send(err);
          }

         res.json(Jobspretty.deadlineDates(jobs));

      });
  },
```

My Helper function:

```js
var moment = require('moment'); // momentjs library
moment().format();


// human readable deadline dates using momentjs

module.exports = {
    deadlineDates: function(jobs) {
        var prettyjobs = [];

        jobs.forEach(function(job) {
            var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(job));
            obj2.deadline  = moment(job.deadline).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");
            prettyjobs.push(obj2);
        });

        return prettyjobs;
    }
};
```